# Concurrency issue with reflection using TryGetValue

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, freeze

We have a legacy CMS system with an issue that seems to be occurring more frequently (likely since the .NET v4 upgrade and running in 64 bit).

(Due to confidentiality, I've had to redact any reference to CMS names)

Below is a snippet from the dump file from our live server.

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.Utils+MethodWithAttributeKey, InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].FindEntry(MethodWithAttributeKey)+f5 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.Utils+MethodWithAttributeKey, InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryGetValue(MethodWithAttributeKey, System.__Canon ByRef)+14 
InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.ConcurrentMap`2[[InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.Utils+MethodWithAttributeKey, InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryGetValue(    MethodWithAttributeKey, System.__Canon ByRef)+8d 
InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.Utils.GetMethodsWithAttribute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]()+1f9 
InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.InternalCMSNameRedactedHandler.DetectServicePage(InternalCMSNameRedacted.Core.ServicePageData)+39c
```

This ultimately leads us too Utils.GetMethodsWithAttribute (that the DetectServicePage uses)

*Background: the DetectServicePage method is called to work out if the page being requested is a "Service Page" instead of a normal content page*

```
   foreach (MethodInfo mi in Utils.GetMethodsWithAttribute<ServicePageHandlerAttribute, ServicePageHandlerContainerAttribute>())
    {
        foreach (ServicePageHandlerAttribute spha in mi.GetCustomAttributes<ServicePageHandlerAttribute>())
        {
            if (urlParts[0] == spha.ServicePage)
            {
                if (data.IsPasswordProtection)
                {
                    if (mi.ReturnType == typeof(ServicePageData))
                    {
                        return mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { data }) as ServicePageData;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mi.ReturnType == typeof(ServicePageData))
                    {
                        return mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { data }) as ServicePageData;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
                    }
                }
                if (spha.EndResponse)
                {
                    Oracle.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This calls Utils.GetMethodsWithAttribute which I believe is the issue (based on the dump file). Code below for this method:

```
  private readonly static ConcurrentMap<MethodWithAttributeKey, ICollection<MethodInfo>> _MethodsWithAttributeCache = new ConcurrentMap<MethodWithAttributeKey, ICollection<MethodInfo>>();

    private readonly static ConcurrentMap<MethodWithAttributeKey, ICollection<string>> _ClassesWithAttributeStringCache = new ConcurrentMap<MethodWithAttributeKey, ICollection<string>>();

    public static ICollection<MethodInfo> GetMethodsWithAttribute<AttributeType, ContainerAttributeType>()
        where AttributeType : Attribute
        where ContainerAttributeType : Attribute
    {
        List<Type> validTypes = null;
        List<MethodInfo> l = new List<MethodInfo>();

        var key = new MethodWithAttributeKey {
            AttributeType = typeof(AttributeType),
            ContainerAttributeType = typeof(ContainerAttributeType)
        };

        ICollection<MethodInfo> methods;
        if (_MethodsWithAttributeCache.TryGetValue(key, out methods)) {
            // If the methods are in the cache and none have disappeared
            if (methods != null && methods.None(m => m == null)) {
                return methods;
            }

            // At least one of the methods we cached last time do not appear to exist now
            // so we need to regenerate from the classesWithAttributeStringCache if possible
            if (_ClassesWithAttributeStringCache.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                validTypes = new List<Type>();

                foreach (var ts in _ClassesWithAttributeStringCache[key])
                {
                    Type type = BuildManager.GetType(ts, false, true);

                    if (type != null) {
                        validTypes.Add(type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (validTypes == null) {
            validTypes = new List<Type>();

            foreach (Assembly assembly in Thread.GetDomain().GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.FullName.StartsWith("System."))) {
                Type[] assemblyTypes = null;
                try {
                    assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
                }
                catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException refEx) {
                    EventLog.Add(refEx);
                    refEx.LoaderExceptions.ToList().ForEach(e => EventLog.Add(e));
                    //throw refEx;
                    continue;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLog.Add(ex);
                    continue;
                }
                if (assemblyTypes != null)
                {
                    foreach (var t in assemblyTypes)
                    {
                        if (t.GetCustomAttributes<ContainerAttributeType>().Count > 0)
                        {
                            validTypes.Add(t);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            List<string> typeStrings = new List<string>();
            validTypes.ToList().ForEach(t => typeStrings.Add(t.AssemblyQualifiedName));
            _ClassesWithAttributeStringCache[key] = typeStrings;
        }

        foreach (Type currentType in validTypes) {
            foreach (var m in currentType.GetMethods()) {
                if (m.GetCustomAttributes<AttributeType>().Count > 0) {
                    l.Add(m);
                }
            }
        }

        // Add into 
        _MethodsWithAttributeCache[key] = l;
        return l;
    }
```

And this uses a CMS specific data stores, ConcurrentMap:

```
public class ConcurrentMap<TKey, TValue> : Map<TKey, TValue>
{
    protected SlimLockWrapper __lock = new SlimLockWrapper();

    protected SlimLockWrapper _lock
    {
        get
        {
            if (__lock == null)
            {
                __lock = new SlimLockWrapper();
            }
            return __lock;
        }
    }

    public ConcurrentMap()
        : this(ProviderDefault)
    {
    }

    public ConcurrentMap(Func<TKey, TValue> provider)
        : base(provider)
    {
    }

    public ConcurrentMap(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : this(ProviderDefault)
    {
    }

    public override TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return this._Get(key); }
        set { this._Set(key, value); }
    }

    public override TValue this[TKey key, TValue fallback]
    {
        get
        {
            return _lock.Read(() => base[key, fallback]);
        }
    }

    public override void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _lock.Write(() => this._Set(key, value));
    }

    public override void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        _lock.Write(() => this._Set(item.Key, item.Value));
    }

    public override void AddRange(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> enumerable)
    {
        _lock.Write(() => {
            foreach (var pair in enumerable) {
                this._Set(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        });
    }

    public override bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.ContainsKey(key));
    }

    public override bool ContainsValue(TValue value)
    {
        return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.ContainsValue(value));
    }

    public override bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.Contains(item));
    }

    public override ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.Keys.ToList()); }
    }

    public override ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.Values.ToList()); }
    }

    public override bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return _lock.Write(() => this._dictionary.Remove(key));
    }

    public override bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        _lock.Lock.EnterReadLock();
        try {
            return this._dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
        finally {
            _lock.Lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {
        _lock.Write(() => this._dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>());
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.Count); }
    }

    public override bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return _lock.Write(() => (this._dictionary as IDictionary<TKey, TValue>).Remove(item));
    }

    public override IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _lock.Read(() => this._dictionary.ToList().GetEnumerator());
    }

    public override void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
    {
        _lock.Read(() => (this._dictionary as IDictionary<TKey, TValue>).CopyTo(array, index));
    }
}
```

I have a feeling it's the custom implementation - concurrencymap, likely there's a native implementation we can use, as this would have been built in .net v2

Comment: Replace the custom collection with a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like a custom ConcurrentDictionary. I'd recommend you to follow Kit's advice ( if you're using old .net version then just copy the ConcurrentDictionary code into your project).
By the way, what issue have you faced? What kind of exception do you see?

Comment: We never actually saw an error, just the process spinning out of control and becoming unresponsive. @AndreyZakharov

Comment: Have you done a performance analysis using PerfView or dotTrace? I guess it could help to understand what is a bottleneck. BTW, I think it worth a try to use standard ConcurrentDictionary before doing a performance analysis.